# Software for hollowing out models for printing on a resin printer

Tags: software

I'm currently using Blender to make models to print on a Resin printer, and Chitubox to hollow the models out. I'm finding that Chitubox is unsatisfactory and leaves lots of internal islands.

Can anybody recomend any alternative software that has a hollowing feature. Preferably a free one?

Answer (score 1):

Consider to check out Lychee Slicer. It has a free version which generates a 30 second advertisement prior to slicing, but the features of the software are implemented quite well and intuitive. I've purchased a limited subscription and haven't found the premium features to be particularly desirable, but not having the advert is almost worth the cost.

I've not used Prusa Slicer, but it is also a free program and can be configured for MSLA as well as FFF printers.